# Credit usage within a task executing a copy statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have some task that execute a copy statement against and external S3 bucket/prefix.  The bucket/prefix has millions of files.  Even when there are no additional files to load the task still takes 7 minutes with the LIST_EXTERNAL_FILES_TIME in query history showing this is where it is spending its time.

Ignoring the design for a moment :)  does the LIST_EXTERNAL_FILES_TIME consume credits?  Will it consume credits even when utilizing a SERVERLESS warehouse?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using Snowpipe? Snowflake will automatically load new files are they arrive serverlessly. There is no list operation because the service has the exact urls of the newly loaded files.

Comment: The answer to your question is no.  However, it does use services compute, which may or may not end up costing your credits depending on whether you are over your free 10% threshold.  There are a lot of best practices that could aid you with what you are trying to do. Snowpipe is one.  Better file management and partitioning on your external stage is another.

Comment: Thank you both.  Reason for not using Snowpipe is the files are on S3, Snowflake on Azure so understanding is Snowpipe is not an option....So the conclusion is It does not consume warehouse compute, so the warehouse defined in the task will not even be provisioned until files are identified that need to be loaded (so serverless task vs defined warehouse task will cost the same).  It does use Services Compute though........ again thanks much...

Answer (score 0):

I would have assumed it would... but:

```
show warehouses;
```

| name | state | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| COMPUTE_WH | SUSPENDED | STANDARD |

```
list @citibike_trips;
```

- 4.2K files listed

```
show warehouses;
```

| name | state | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| COMPUTE_WH | SUSPENDED | STANDARD |

So it seems the fetch is on the CLOUD_COMPUTE, which you will get billed for the amount of the days usage that is over 10% of you normal compute.